# Scanning a whole line into a list

Tags: vb.net, string, list

I have a string (that changes every occurrence of it) that looks like this: 
`<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up> <Press V><Press Up><Press Q><Press Up><Press L>` I need to read every instance of the letter after the word `Press` and store them in a list, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I have this code now that reads in the whole string, and every instance of the letter after the word `Press` but it doesn't store them in a list instantly, but rather than after iteration.

```
Dim keyString = command.ToString
    Dim allKeys As New List(Of String)
    Dim pattern = "Press "
    Dim index = keyString.IndexOf(pattern)
    While index >= 0
        index += pattern.Length
        Dim endIndex = keyString.IndexOf(">", index)
        If endIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim nextKey = keyString.Substring(index, endIndex - index)
            allKeys.Add(nextKey)
            index = keyString.IndexOf(pattern, endIndex + 1)
```

So I guess, in short version, how would I make it so it scans the whole string and stores each instance of the character after `Press` into the list `allKeys` ?

Comment: Your code appears to do exactly what you want, i.e. put the each key after "Press " in to a list called allKeys. What exactly is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regular expression (RegEx) to accomplish this task more easily.  If you haven't been exposed to regular expressions, they can be a bit daunting, but as you can see, it's worth it to take the time to learn the technology.  Regular expressions are very powerful, and they are a perfect fit for this type of problem.

```
Dim keyString As String = "<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up> <Press V><Press Up><Press Q><Press Up><Press L>"
Dim regEx As New Regex("<Press (?<key>.*?)>")
Dim allKeys As New List(Of String)()
For Each m As Match In regEx.Matches(keyString)
    allKeys.Add(m.Groups("key").Value)
Next
```

The regular expression I used in the example is `<Press (?<key>.*?)>`.  The parts of the expression mean:

- `<Press` - The matching string must begin with these characters.
- `(?<key>` - Begins a group of characters named `key`.
- `.*` - Matches any character any number of times.
- `?` - Makes the expression non-greedy.  In other words, the match for any character any number of times only includes up to the first `>` character, which is specified later.  If the question mark was not there, the pattern would be greedy, so it would match the entire string up until the last `>` character.
- `)` - Ends the named group.
- `>` - The matching string must end with this character.

In simple terms, the regular expression defines a search pattern with an advanced wildcard.  If we were using `*` as a simple wildcard, it would look like `<Press *>`.  In other words we want to find all of the instances of a sub-string that starts with `<Press`, ends with `>`, and has anything in between.  In the RegEx pattern, however, where the wildcard portion can be much more powerful, the wildcard is not a simple `*` character, but rather, the wildcard is `(?<key>.*?)` which not only instructs it to match any sub-string, but also assigns the name `key` to the wildcard.  Assigning it a name means that we can easily reference it in code to get its value.

The example code creates a regular expression object using that pattern, then runs a search on the `keyString` variable by calling `regEx.Matches(keyString)`.  That method returns a collection of `Match` objects which represent each match of the pattern in `keyString`.  Then, it calls `m.Groups("key").Value` to get the value of the `key` group (the wildcard part) from each match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions:

```
Dim allKeys As New List(Of String)
Dim s As String = "<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up> <Press V><Press Up><Press Q><Press Up>   <Press L>"

Dim regx As Regex = New Regex("<(Press) ([\w+\s*]+)(>)")
Dim mcollection As MatchCollection = regx.Matches(s)
For Each m As Match In mcollection
    allKeys.Add(m.Groups(2).Value)
Next
```

Comment: This will match all elements, such as `<Left` and `<Right`, not just the `<Press` elements.  Also, this only works if the value after the word `Press` is a single word.

Comment: It ignores everything before because of the spaces. It only matches word characters (without spaces) followed immediately by the >

Comment: Yes, I just tried it and it results in `{"Up", "Up, "V", "Up", Q", "Up", "L"}`, but it should be `{"V", "Up", Q", "Up", "L"}` (skipping the first two mouse-related elements.  Secondly, if I change `s` to `"<Press Page Up>"`, then it results in `"Up"`, rather than `"Page Up"`.

Comment: Then I misunderstood the guys request. I actually expected the result {"Up", "Up, "V", "Up", Q", "Up", "L"}.

Comment: made some amendments, admittedly the patterns not as clean as yours @StevenDoggart :)

Comment: Yup, that fixed it (+1).  I changed the group index for you, though :)  It's always interesting to see all the various RegEx patterns people come up with to solve the same problem.  It's helpful to see how else it can be done.

Comment: thanks, and you're right: there's so many different ways to solve a problem with Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple sub that will parse your string and add to the list, using the list you pass to it, which should update as each item is added:

```
Private Sub FillList(ByRef PressList As List(Of String), PressString As String)
    For Each token As String In PressString.Split({"Press"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
        If Not token.StartsWith("<") Then PressList.Add(token.Split(">"c)(0))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Very elegant example.  My only suggestion would be to make it a `Function` which returns the list rather then passing the list into it.  Also, as a `Sub` routine, the `PressList` parameter does not need to be `ByRef`.  If it was `ByVal`, it would still work either way.  With reference types, like `List(Of T)`, the only reason you would need it to be `ByRef` would be if you need to change the variable to point to a new or different list object.  If all you are doing is adding items to the list, that's not actually changing the value of the reference variable.

Comment: `ByRef` would be a reference to the reference to the object, whereas `ByVal` would be a copy of the reference to the object.  Either way, it's still just a reference to the single same object.  In neither case does it make a copy of the object.

Comment: According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ddck1z30%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) the data itself is copied, when ByVal is used, essentially creating a new object. `Although the passing mechanism can affect the performance of your code, the difference is usually insignificant. One exception to this is a value type passed ByVal. In this case, Visual Basic copies the entire data contents of the argument.`

Comment: Right.  That's what I was trying to say, however inadequately.  With "value types" like `Integer`, the value is copied, but with "reference types", the referenced object is not copied, only the reference itself is copied.  In other words, with reference types, the value of the variable is nothing more than the memory location indicating where the object actually exists, so passing it `ByVal` doesn't copy the object, it merely copies the memory location.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would tokenize the string using .Split and split it into tags.  If your tags have spaces between them, you might need to parse those out.  Try something like this:

```
Dim allKeys As New List(Of String)
Dim myString As String = "<Left Mouse Up> <Right Mouse Up> <Press V><Press Up><Press Q><Press Up><Press L>"
Dim tokens As IEnumerable(Of String) = myString.Replace("> <", "><").Split("><")
tokens = (From t In tokens Where t.Contains("<Press "))
For Each t In tokens
  allKeys.Add(t.Replace("<Press ", String.Empty).Replace(">", String.Empty))
Next t
```

Comment: This is a good start to an example showing how to do it with `Split`, as an alternative to RegEx, but unfortunately it doesn't work, as is.  First, replacing `> <` with `><`, while it works in this example, won't work if there is more than one space between elements.  Second, when you split the string on `><`, it does not include the opening bracket in most of the resulting sub-strings.  So, for instance, `Press V` won't match because it does not contain `<Press `.

Comment: Did you actually try it?  It works for me.  The list contains V, Up, Q, Up, L.  And it can easily be modified to trim spaces between the brackets if the spacing is inconsistent.

Comment: Also, when I split the string, every single sub-string contains the opening bracket.  In actuality, the closing brackets are missing (not like you really need them anyways, nor do you need the opening brackets, for that matter).  At least try running the code before you say it doesn't work.  That being said, I do think the RegEx is a more elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: Ah, oops.  I did try it before I posted it, but `Option Strict` threw me off.  You have that option turned off.  I have it on, so when I pasted the code it complained that `Split("><")` was invalid.  Rather than changing the setting, i "fixed" the code to `Split({"><"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`, but to correctly mimic what `Option Strict Off` does, I should have changed it to to `Split(CChar("><"))`, which is actually the same as just saying `Split(">"c)`.  That does happen to work in this example, but it's probably not exactly what you intended.  In any case, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries. I did have it off for this particular class and didn't even realize it.  You're correct in your assumption that my intention was not to split the string by > chars.  I suppose that I would have to replace "><" with some other delimiter for the .Split to work as intended.